# Grafana Gantt Chart parameters from prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, gantt-chart

I'm trying to create a gantt chart for my app jobs  execution time, I got the metric values from prometheus and tried multiple promQl to get the required values to get the gantt chart but couldn't. the task name is from the metric label, I also tried this but was not successful `batch_job_start_running_time,batch_job_stop_running_time,{{job}}`
any idea ?
[image]

Comment: show the data table